# Form with multiple submit buttons, how to set the default enter key action - barcode scanner input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck on this issue.  I have a simple form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="barcode1">
<input type="submit" name="barcode1" value="Submit Barcode1">
<input type="text" name="barcode2">
<input type="submit" name="barcode2" value="Submit Barcode2">
</form>
```

I'm using a barcode scanner to enter the data into the text field.  The scanner records a series of numbers, followed by a 'Enter' command.

When I scan into the barcode1 field, it works perfectly, the form is submitted by the scanner's 'Enter' command.

When I scan into barcode2 field, it submits the form using the barcode1 submit.

Is it possible, to change the default submit button on a form with multiple submit buttons?  Perhaps I could set the default submit button when I focus on the text field for that submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var toClick;
    $(":text").focus(function() {
        toClick = $(this);
    });
    $('form').keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(toClick).next('input[type="submit"]').click();
        }
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caitlinadian/2j2kg0uh/3/)